# ajax request working locally but not on live server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel 5, and have created a simple ajax request to fire of a function in model.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fa-eye').click(function(){
        //we get the data-service value here
        var serviceID = $(this).data('service');

        //every request in laravel requires a token for security, so i set the headers here
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
        });

        jQuery.ajax({
            //here i am going to my route and adding the serviceID
            url:'/addwatchlist/' + serviceID,
            type: 'GET',//set the request to GET
            success: function( data ){
                console.log(data);
                //this is simply the serviceID that we sent to the controller seen above
                $('.fa-eye').each(function(){
                    if($(this).data('service') == data){
                        $(this).addClass('watchlisted');
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, b, c) {
                console.log("xhr=" + xhr + " b=" + b + " c=" + c);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Okay this is my Route that it should hit.

```
Route::get('/addwatchlist/{id}','WatchlistController@addWatchList');
```

This is the controller action it then hits:

```
public function addWatchList($serviceID)
{
    //simply adds it to the database
    WatchList::saveWatchList($this->userid,$serviceID);

    return $serviceID;
    //this sends back the serviceID back to the ajax success method, the same serviceID that was sent here.
}
```

Ok so thats it, on my local host it works fine with no problem, now when i push the changes to my dev server i get the following errors.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas??

Comment: Well it seems to have something to do with it not being able to find your class `WatchlistController`. Why? We can't tell.

Comment: I dont know why though , because it finds it fine on my local and it is there

Comment: You are calling a class `HealthWatchInformatics` that is not an instance of WatchlistController controller, you need to inject it or initialize at the constructor.

Comment: i have this at the top of my watchlist controller : use HealthwatchInformatics\WatchList; so i am injecting the class to the controller

Comment: What namespace do you have on your `WatchlistController`?